# WPF DataGrid Alternating Row Background doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I've tried several things but the AlternationIndex in the Trigger does not work at all.

If I use

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,40,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
  AlternatingRowBackground="DimGray" AlternationCount="1"
```

it works but then the  IsMouseOver Trigger won't work on the alternating rows.

So I do the thing everyone is writing here:

```
    <Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF574F4F"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF8B1515" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
...
...
 <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" Margin="10,40,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  IsReadOnly="True" 
                  ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
                  RowHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowHeaderStyle}"
                  CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" 
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"....


        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Author" Binding="{Binding Author}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

With that code the AliceBlue won't show up. Tried everything but I have no clue why it does nothing. AlternationIndex 0 works as background but not 1, 2 or 3. 
As Binding Source I've used a DataTable
Just a simple class with some methods. I'm coming from Java 1.6 SWT, that fancy stuff is all new to me

```
 table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
 table.Columns.Add("Description", typeof(string));
 table.Columns.Add("Author", typeof(string));     
 ....
 table.Rows.Add(name, description, author );
```

Setting the dataContext with the return value from the upper code

```
 dataGrid.DataContext = dTable.getTable();
```

Has anyone an idea why it doesn't work.. it really drives me nuts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to also set the DataGrid's property AlternationCount="2"

Comment: Oh man.. hugs for you! :D  Used AlternationCount only with AlternatingRowBackground but not with the Triggers. Thanks :)